# Как исключить лишний пробел в данной регулярке?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Имеются строки вида:

```
проверка , некое 123 свойство больше чем другое свойство 456 ,  тоже проверка
```

Которые надо разбить на логические группы НЕЧТО больше/меньше/равно ЧЕМ ДРУГОЕ

Используется шаблон, который разбивает фразу на три группы: VAL1(значение1), CONDITION(логическое условие), VAL2(значение2)

```
\b(?<VAL1>[\w\d\s\\\/]+)\b(?<CONDITION>((больше)|(меньше)))\s+(чем)?(?<VAL2>[\w\d\s\\\/]+)\b
```

Результат приемлемый:

```
Group `VAL1`    14-33   `некое 123 свойство `
Group `CONDITION`   33-39   `больше`
Group 3.    33-39   `больше`
Group 4.    33-39   `больше`
Group 6.    40-43   `чем`
Group `VAL2`    43-63   ` другое свойство 456`
```

Но вот как исключить пробелы по краям VAL1 и VAL2? К сожалению пока не особо силен в регулярках.

Да и вообще правильный ли подход к парсингу подобных текстов. Может оптимальнее использовать просмотр назад/вперед или что-то еще?

Comment: перед открытием скобок захватывающих VAL2 добавьте `\s*`, что бы показать что в этом месте могут быть пробелы

Comment: С VAL2 помогло. А как быть с VAL1, в который попадает пробел в конец? По аналогии что-то не выходит.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Oo7NgK/1  там еще ленивость добавить в первые скобки, а то они следующий пробел всегда хватают

Comment: И что то в condition скобок многовато, не нужны они там https://regex101.com/r/Oo7NgK/2

Comment: Спасибо. Что-то регулярки взрывают мой, привыкший к обычному структурному программированию, мозг :)